# AWS Nested Stacks - Referencing a Parent Stack's Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to pass resources (ApiGatewayRestApi and a custom authorizer) to a nested stack through stack parameters, however, they continually fail with `Embedded stack <stack_name> was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create`. Here's my set up in Serverless:

**Parent Stack**

```
{
    ...
    "NestedStack": {
    "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
    "Properties": {
      "Parameters": {
        "ServerlessDeploymentBucket": {
          "Ref": "ServerlessDeploymentBucket"
        },
        "ApiGatewayRestApi": {
          "Ref": "ApiGatewayRestApi"
        },
        "AuthDashjwtApiGatewayAuthorizer": {
          "Ref": "AuthDashjwtApiGatewayAuthorizer"
        },
      },
      "TemplateURL": "..."
    }
  },
}
```

**Nested Stack**

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Nested Stack",
  "Parameters": {
    "ServerlessDeploymentBucket": { "Type": "String" },
    "ApiGatewayRestApi": {
      "Description": "Rest API",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "AuthDashjwtApiGatewayAuthorizer": { "Type": "String" },
  },
  "Resources": {
      "ApiGatewayMethodEventsEventidVarStreamsPost": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
        "Properties": {
          "HttpMethod": "POST",
          "RequestParameters": {},
          "ResourceId": { "Ref": "ApiGatewayResourceEventsEventidVarStreams" },
          "RestApiId": { "Ref": "ApiGatewayRestApi" },
          "AuthorizationType": "CUSTOM",
          "AuthorizerId": { "Ref": "AuthDashjwtApiGatewayAuthorizer" },
          ...
        }
        ...
     }
     ...
}
```

Am I not referencing or passing in parameters correctly?

**Update based on comments**
Unless I'm missing something, the only error message in the CF section of the console is:

```
Embedded stack <stac_name> was not successfully created: The 
following resource(s) failed to create: [PatchDasheventLogGroup, 
PostDashstreamLogGroup, GetDashstreamsLogGroup, GetDasheventsLogGroup, 
ApiGatewayRestApi, GetDasheventLogGroup, PostDasheventLogGroup, 
AuthDashjwtApiGatewayAuthorizer]
```

as far as log groups go, they look like this:

```
"GetDasheventLogGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::Logs::LogGroup",
  "Properties": { 
     "LogGroupName": "/aws/lambda/live-api-local-get-event"
   }
}
```

**Update 2**
The log group issue was due to these logs being moved from the parent stack to the nested stack and needing a new name. In the [LogGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loggroup.html) docs I found:

> If you specify a name, you cannot perform updates that require replacement of this resource. You can perform updates that require no or some interruption. If you must replace the resource, specify a new name.

This looks like it may have solved the issue... Some more testing is needed to confirm!

Comment: In the CloudFormation section of the AWS console you can filter by stacks in the `Failed` state.  You should be able to find your nested stack there and then figure out exactly what resource within it is failing (and maybe even get a better error message as to why)

Comment: Yeah, look at the events for the child stack to get a more useful error

Comment: Can you respond with the solution and mark this as answered?

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @speshak eventually lead me to the answer. I didn't need to filter by `Failed` state, but rather `Deleted`. This allowed me to see the logs for the nested stack that was created, then deleted with more specific messaging.

What this ended up showing me is that the `update-stack` process was applying the nested stacks to my current set up before removing all the resources from, what would become, the root stack. So the true problem was that I was accidentally trying to create duplicate resources -- AWS saw a resource in a nested stack that matched the root stack, and kicked out with a validation error even though the resource would have been removed from the root stack... eventually.